# $\|.\|_2$ closure of a set which is dense in $L^2[0,2\pi].$

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

The following is an exercise of Conway's Functional analysis, [chapter 1, section 5](http://books.google.com/books?id=ix4P1e6AkeIC&pg=PA23).

Let $L=\{f\in C[0,2\pi]|f(0)=f(2\pi)\}$ and show that $L$ is dense in $L^2[0,2\pi]$.

Answer (score 3):

Take $f\in L^2[0,2\pi]$, and an $\varepsilon>0$. As $C[0,2\pi]$ is dense in $L^2[0,2\pi]$, then there exists a $g\in C[0,2\pi]$, such that $\|f-g\|<\varepsilon/2$.

Take now $g_\delta$ to be equal to $g$ in $[\delta,2\pi-\delta]$, to vanish at $0$ and $2\pi$, and to be linear in the intervals $[0,\delta]$ and $[2\pi-\delta,2\pi]$. Then choose $\delta$, so that
$\|g-g_\delta\|<\varepsilon/2$, and you got what you need.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, we use simple functions to approximation $L^2$. Then use continuous function to approximation.
(1)For any $\varepsilon$, there exist a simple function $I$ on $R$ with compact support set, which satisfies that $\int_0^{2\pi}|f-I|^2<\varepsilon$.
(2)The statement you mention above.